# Get Closest Value With GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by

I'm having issues with getting the closest result depending on the data that will be given by the user. The user gives me the Length, Width, and Height of a box then I compute the volume and compare them to the available volumes in the database grouped by country.

I have created the fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c8cf07/3).

```
+====+=====+==========+=================+===============+======+=====+======+
| id |BU_ID|country_id| Name            |Description    |Length|Width|Height|
+====+=====+==========+=================+===============+======+=====+======+
|164 |117  |1         |Jumbo Box        |Biggest        |24.00 |25.00|17.00 |
|165 |117  |1         |Regular          |Large Box      |24.00 |20.00|17.00 |
|166 |117  |1         |Medium           |Medium Box     |18.00 |18.00|16.00 |
|167 |117  |1         |Bulilit          |Small          |18.00 |9.00 |16.00 |
|254 |117  |2         |Bulilit Indonesia|Small Indonesia|18.00 |9.00 |16.00 |
|255 |117  |2         |Jumbo Indonesia  |Biggest        |24.00 |25.00|17.00 |
|256 |117  |2         |Medium Indonesia |Medium Box     |18.00|18.00 |16.00 |
|257 |117  |2         |Regular Indonesia|Large Box      |24.00|20.00 |17.00 |
+====+=====+==========+=================+===============+======+=====+======+
```

If the `Length * Width * Height` of the box that the user gave is `3375` then this should be the result:

```
+====+=====+==========+=================+===============+======+=====+======+
| id |BU_ID|country_id| Name            |Description    |Length|Width|Height|
+====+=====+==========+=================+===============+======+=====+======+
|166 |117  |1         |Medium           |Medium Box     |18.00 |18.00|16.00 |
|256 |117  |2         |Medium Indonesia |Medium Box     |18.00 |18.00|16.00 |
+====+=====+==========+=================+===============+======+=====+======+
```

I was able to get ALL the data that are equal or greater than `3375` but I can't get the 'closest' ones.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: So what is closest?  Does it include boxes that are too small?? Or do you want just the first few >= to the minimum, where few is one or two or ...?

Comment: Specify your MySQL version explicitly. Does you use version 5.6 as specified in your fiddle?

Answer (score -1):

After trying multiple times and with the help of the answer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657695/getting-wrong-values-for-other-columns-when-i-select-maxupdated-date)**, I was able to get the right query:

```
SELECT t1.`id`, t1.`BU_ID`, t1.`country_id`, 
       t1.`Name`, t1.`Description`, t1.`Length`, 
       t1.`Width`, t1.`Height`, t3.min_lwh
FROM boxes AS t1
JOIN (SELECT MIN(t2.Length * t2.Width * t2.Height) AS min_lwh
      FROM boxes AS t2 WHERE (t2.Length * t2.Width * t2.Height) >= 3775
   ) AS t3
ON (t1.Length * t1.Width * t1.Height) = t3.min_lwh;
```

Answer (score -1):

One more solution:

```sql
SELECT id, BU_ID, country_id, Name, Description, Length, Width, Height
FROM ( SELECT id, BU_ID, country_id, Name, Description, Length, Width, Height, 
              @rank := @rank + (@volume != Length * Width * Height) _rank_, 
              @volume := Length * Width * Height
       FROM boxes, ( SELECT @volume := 0, @rank := 0 ) variables
       WHERE ( Length * Width * Height ) >= 3775
       ORDER BY Length * Width * Height ASC ) subquery
WHERE _rank_ = 1
```

And the solution applicable if MySQL server version is 8+:

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT id, BU_ID, country_id, Name, Description, Length, Width, Height,
              RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Length * Width * Height ASC) _rank_
              FROM boxes
              WHERE ( Length * Width * Height ) >= 3775 )
SELECT id, BU_ID, country_id, Name, Description, Length, Width, Height
FROM cte
WHERE _rank_ = 1
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f02ef5a7ec3f5e8c4175a14a3d7d99e0)